# HTML to> AJAX to> Node to> Arduino

Tags: html, node.js, ajax, arduino

I'm a noob to Node and need some help.
Here's my current setup:[Current Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9RK6.png)

One the one side I have a basic HTML website with a few <inputs>.  The inputs are assigned to variables via onclick event (jscript). Each input has its own button (not using a form)

One the other side I have Nodejs controlling a simple Arduino circuit via Johnny Five library.

My question:
**Can I "pass" the values from my website to Nodejs without using AJAX?  Or is AJAX pretty much my only option?**

Comment: What's wrong with AJAX?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Ajax :-)  Just want to know what my options are.

Comment: you can use a form instead of ajax. _target_ a hidden iframe to make it behave like ajax

Comment: I haven't done that before. Thanx for the advice. Will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I made something similar, and I used [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to communicate between browser and node js

Just look at an [example](https://socket.io/demos/chat/) and you should be able to make your own!

In my [setup](https://imgur.com/a/Dn3WC) I used a VPS (static public ip) with node js to provide a relay between the client and the rpi (which also had node js and controlled the arduino)

Comment: Epic!! thank you for sharing. Your setup looks awesome.